# Calculating the total sales value for a customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a script to return to me the total sales value for a customer in MS SQL.

However, I am not being returned the correct amount when I enter the script. I believe it could be to do with the way I have joined my tables or I am missing out on a SUM function somewhere. Either way I'm stumped any help will be greatly appreciated.
Edit: Sorry forgot to mention it has to take in a variable at @CustomerName to be used with different customers

```
create procedure TotalSalesValue @CustomerName varchar(30)
AS
SELECT top 1 @CustomerName, sum(quantity * SellingPrice) amount
from tblCustomer c 
join tblProduct p
  on c.CustomerID=p.ProductID
join tblSOLine so
  on so.ProductID = p.ProductID
group by c.CustomerName
order by amount desc
```

I have included my database diagram as well, if required. Thanks again!

Database diagram:

[image]

Comment: `SELECT top 1 c.CustomerName...`,i.e .without `@`?

Answer (score 0):

May be so

```
create procedure TotalSalesValue @CustomerName varchar(30)
AS
   SELECT q0.CustomerName, sum(q0.amount) as 'amount' FROM (
      SELECT c.CustomerName, sum(so.quantity * p.SellingPrice) as 'amount'
      from tblCustomer c 
      join tblProduct p
        on c.CustomerID=p.ProductID
      join tblSOLine so
        on so.ProductID = p.ProductID
      where c.CustomerName=@CustomerName) as q0
```

Procedure selects all amounts for target customer by name.

Comment: Why would you write this using a subquery?

Comment: I decided to remove subquery. it is not needed here, assuming that the customer name is unique

Comment: Thanks for the quick response unfortunately thats not quite cracked it as im getting a lower amount than before when running, when i execute without a top 1 i get these results and im thinking maybe i need to add them all together aswell? Thanks again.  [other results] (http://imgur.com/Be69Mjh)

Comment: @George Rees, try the new variant

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a table on the SELECT, you need to join with tblSOHeader in ordre to take into account all Sales Orders

```
create procedure TotalSalesValue @CustomerName varchar(30)
AS
SELECT top 1 @CustomerName, sum(SO.quantity * p.SellingPrice) amount
from tblCustomer c 
inner join tblSOHeader h ON h.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
inner join tblSOLine so ON so.SOHeaderID=h.SOHeaderID
inner join tblProduct p ON so.ProductID=p.ProductID
group by c.CustomerName
order by amount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation on issues with your query:**

1. You were joining `tblProduct` with `tblCustomer`, which is not possible as per schema
2. You must join with `tblSoHeader` which has `customerID` and then join that to `tblSOLine` and then to `tblProduct`
3. Finally since you need it for a given customer, that `customerName` must be in the `where` clause

Please try the below query

```
create procedure TotalSalesValue @CustomerName varchar(30)
AS
    SELECT CustomerName, sum(so.quantity * p.SellingPrice) amount
    from tblCustomer c 
        join tblSoHeader H on c.CustomerID = H.CustomerID
        join tblSOLine so on so.SoHeaderID = H.SoheaderID
        join tblProduct p on p.ProductID = so.ProductID
    where CustomerName=@CustomerName
    group by c.CustomerName
```